# How do you change Rotom forms in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I just caught Rotom, but it was the normal-form Rotom. I would like the Mow Rotom, but I don't know how to change it's form.

Is it possible? If it is, where can I change Rotom's form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change Rotom's form in the 2nd floor of Sycamore's Lab, in Lumiose City.

Comment: @pokemonlover - If lemedli's answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark underneath the vote count. This awards extra reputation points to lemedli, as well as a small bonus to yourself :)